# Page layout and margins

Tags: header-footer, margins, minipage

My CV is currently the image on the left, but how would I shift my name up and make the format (structure of the page etc.) of my CV which is on the left of the image below, like the cv on the right of the image below?

My latex code (my cv on the left image) is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\title{\bfseries\Huge John Doe}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
Address Line 4\\
Address Line 5
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 123-456789\\
Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: My citizenship
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008--2012&MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006--2008&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Employment}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--today&{\bf Company Name.} Head of Department. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\end{itemize} 
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards and Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&Gold medal.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006&Silver medal.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Organisational Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&This event.\vspace{5pt}\\
\end{tabular}


\section*{Languages}
English, Spanish, French, German


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just work without `\maketitle` and set your name for example like `\begin{center}\bfseries\Huge John Doe \end{center}`.

Comment: and for shifting some things up, you can use \vspace{-value}, \vspace*{-value}, or \vskip-value

Comment: ... or use some dedicated packages for CVs like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, do have a look at a package such as `moderncv` for ways that others have gone about organizing a cv. In the code below, I've tried to approximate the sought-after look by following these "rules"

- use only two columns
- use standardized column widths (e.g., 1.75cm and "remainder of available textwidth")
- no indentation of first lines anywhere (set `\parindent` to 0pt throughout, and suppress indentation of material in left-hand most column of `tabular[*x]` environments)
- use a font that's a bit "darker" than Computer Modern. I suggest you start with `Palatino` (provided by the `mathpazo` package) and go on from there. Don't use Times Roman unless you want the resume to look utterly bland

  ```
  \documentclass[10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \newcolumntype{P}{p{1.75cm}}
  \usepackage{url}
  \urlstyle{same}
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  \usepackage{mathpazo}
  \begin{document}
  {\centering 
  \bfseries\Huge John Doe        
  }

  \vspace{1cm}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
  Address Line 1 & Mobile: 123-456789\\
  Address Line 2 & Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
  Address Line 3 & Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
  Address Line 4 & Citizenship: My citizenship\\
  Address Line 5 & Website: \url{some.verylongnamegoeshere.net}
  \end{tabular*}

  \section*{Education}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}PX@{}}
  2008--2012&MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country\\[5pt]
  2006--2008&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.
  \end{tabularx}

  \section*{Employment}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}PX@{}}
  2011--today&\textbf{Company Name.} Head of Department. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here.\\
  &\begin{itemize}
  \item Add my job description here.
  \item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
  \item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
  \item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
  \end{itemize}
  ```

  \end{tabularx}

  ```
  \section*{Awards and Achievements}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}PX@{}}
  2008&Gold medal.\\[5pt]
  2006&Silver medal.
  \end{tabularx}

  \section*{Organisational Experience}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}PX@{}}
  2008&This event.\vspace{5pt}
  \end{tabularx}

  \section*{Languages}
  English, Spanish, French, German
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]